# Oracle Database Migration Risks 10g -> 11g

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I'm having and WindowsForm, .NET 4.0 application that relies on an Oracle10g db, using ODP.NET. The database operations used by the app are pretty much standard insert/update/select and OracleBulkCopy.
I also want to change the CharacterSet.

I'm thinking to upgrade to 11g, and I would like to know what would be the risks. What should i be testing afterwards to make sure that everything is OK ?

Comment: In any case you would have to test the whole app, but i don't think upgrading would break anything existing since all would be supported for backward compatability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CharacterSet change can be interesting and could cause most side effects. Depending on how complex your queries are, you could see quite a performance improvement compared to the old 10g database. This of course assumes a good configured 11g database, not just a 11g database running with 10g settings.

Normally for a major database upgrade I would go for full regression test, concentrating on the database interaction. For the CharacterSet conversion there might be a little more work, depending on where and how the data flows.

Are you planning to use new features of 11g?
How is the application setup?
What volumes does the app handle?
How big is the db?
How many concurrent users?

Comment: Thanks for your ans! no, no new feature will be used, about 10-15 concurent users, just one schema having about 100 objects (tables, views, stored procs, etc). There are tables with up to 50 millions records. Yes, the character set change is the one that might cause issue. Everything else i expect to work in the same way.